# JQuery: Centering Images within a div

Tags: jquery, image

community!

I've been trying to center images within 3 seperate divs and thats the code that I came up with till now:

```
$(document).ready(imgresize);
$(window).on('resize',imgresize);

function imgresize() {

var rk = $(".rk").css('width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
var img = $("img").css('width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
var calc = (img - rk) / 2;
var calc2 = calc - (calc * 2) + 'px';

$("img").css('margin-left', calc2);
}
```

It takes the current width of the image-wrapper (for example 200px).
Then it takes the width of the image itself (f.e. 180px)

does some maths and in the end it comes up with 20px beeing the difference and half of it needed as a margin value to center the image.

This works fine but there is just one problem.
If I got 3 different images which all have a different width, then this funktion takes the width of just one of the images and gives the other two wether too little or too much margin.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
   <div class="rk">
       <img src="img_1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="rk">
       <img src="img_2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="rk">
       <img src="img_3.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!
-Thomas

---

EDIT: example for the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/R9eZu/3/

The only thing I really need to know is how to seperate the functions for each img and its container.
Does it maybe work with ".this"? - Sorry, I'm really new to JQuery/Javascript :)

---

EDIT 2: FOr better understandig:

The images should proportionally fill their containers - to that point its no problem. What I want to do now is to shift every image inside of its container to a individual value, so that the images are all centered horizontally.
For example:

```
    -image container width: 200px
    -img1w: 300px
    -img2w: 240px
    -img3w: 420px

    ... calculation is: (imgwidth - containerwidth) / 2 ...

    img1 would be shifted 50px,
    img2 would be shifted 20px,
    img3 would be shifted 110px.
```

Comment: is this not an option? http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/R9eZu/1/ - using css to centre the image rather than javascript

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that unfortunately doesn't work for a fluid layout :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using foreach to loop in class. I thisk this is that you have asked

```
function imgresize() {
    $(".rk").each(function (index, data) {    
        var rk = $(this).width();
        var img = $(this).find(">:first-child").width();
        var calc = (img - rk) / 2;
        var calc2 = calc - (calc * 2) + 'px';
        $(this).find(">:first-child").css('margin-left', calc2);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R9eZu/5/

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't solve the problem :/ - edited the first post!

Comment: No, sorry :/ The images should proportionally fill their containers - to that point its no problem. What I want to do now is to shift every image inside of its container to a individual value, so that the images are centered horizontally. For example: image container width: 200px, img1w: 300px, img2w: 240px, img3w: 420px; ... calculation is: (imgwidth - containerwidth) / 2 ... img1 would be shifted 50px, img2 20px and img3 110px

Comment: edited the first post again - better readable there ;) thanks for helping